# MySQL - How to simplify this query?

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a query which i want to simplify:

```
select
      sequence,
      1 added
      from scoredtable
      where score_timestamp=1292239056000
      and sequence
      not in (select sequence from scoredtable where score_timestamp=1292238452000)
      union
select
      sequence,
      0 added
      from scoredtable
      where score_timestamp=1292238452000
      and sequence
      not in (select sequence from scoredtable where score_timestamp=1292239056000);
```

Any ideas? basically i want to extract from the same table all the sequences that are different betweent two timestamp values. With a colum "added" which represents if a row is new or if a row has been deleted.

Source table:

```
score_timestamp             sequence
1292239056000               0
1292239056000               1
1292239056000               2
1292238452000               1
1292238452000               2
1292238452000               3
```

Example between (1292239056000, 1292238452000) 
Query result (2 rows):

```
sequence added
3        1
0        0
```

Example between (1292238452000, 1292239056000) 
Query result (2 rows):

```
sequence added
0        1
3        0
```

Example between (1292239056000, 1292239056000)
Query result (0 rows):

```
sequence added
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query gets all `sequences` that appear only once within both timestamps, and checks if it occurs for the first or for the second timestamp.

```
SELECT
  sequence,
  CASE WHEN MIN(score_timestamp) = 1292239056000 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS added
FROM scoredtable
WHERE score_timestamp IN ( 1292239056000, 1292238452000 )
  AND ( 1292239056000 <> 1292238452000 )   -- No rows, when timestamp is the same
GROUP BY sequence
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

It returns your desired result:

```
sequence added
3       1
0       0
```

Comment: Oops! it is not the same query! I have added more examples which are not satisfied with this query :( For example when comparing with the same timestamp or when comparing in the reverser order (i want to compare higher with lower timestamps also)....

Comment: @user490505: I changed my query to cover comparing the same timestamps too. Reverse order already worked for me (make sure to change first occurrence of timestamp too).

Answer (score 0):

Given two timestamps

```
SET @ts1 := 1292239056000
SET @ts2 := 1292238452000
```

you can get your additions and deletes with:

```
SELECT s1.sequence AS sequence, 0 as added
FROM scoredtable s1 LEFT JOIN
     scoredtable s2 ON 
                       s2.score_timestamp = @ts2 AND
                       s1.sequence = s2.sequence
WHERE
     s1.score_timestamp = @ts1 AND
     s2.score_timestampe IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT s2.sequence, 1
FROM scoredtable s1 RIGHT JOIN
     scoredtable s2 ON s1.score_timestamp = @ts1 AND
                       s1.sequence = s2.sequence
WHERE
     s2.score_timestamp = @ts2 AND
     s1.score_timestampe IS NULL
```

depending on the number of rows and the statistics the above query might perform better then group by and having count(*) = 1 version (i think that will always need full table scan, while the above union should be able to do 2 x [anti-join](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) which might fare better)

If you have substantial data set, do let us know which is faster (test with [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html) for comparable results)